# why this jsp page giving me no result only null values

Tags: java, jsp

i have tested my code all stdData is giving me correct values but when i run it on jsp page it gives me null value why this happening any correction needed or some other logic so i can undo my mistake in code and get the correct values please give me guidance on this.

**This is the class where I configured database specification**

```
    package school;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    public class ReadingStd {

        String conURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
                + "databaseName=schoolDB;user=fas;password=24071982";
        List<String> stdData = new ArrayList<String>(222);
        String std = null;

        public void readStd(String stdId) {




            try {

                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conURL);
                System.out.println("faisal:");
                String sqlQuery = "select * from schoolDB.dbo.addstudent where sid = '" + stdId + "'";
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                System.out.println("faisal11:");
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

                while(rs.next()) {
                    //System.out.println(":5465");
                    stdData.add(0,rs.getString("sid"));
                    //System.out.println(rs.getString("sid"));
                    //std = rs.getString("sid");
                    stdData.add(1, rs.getString("name"));
                    //System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
                    stdData.add(2, rs.getString("fname"));
                    stdData.add(3, rs.getString("dob"));
                    stdData.add(4, rs.getString("classs"));
                    stdData.add(5, rs.getString("occupation_father"));
                    stdData.add(6, rs.getString("edu_father"));
                    stdData.add(7, rs.getString("email"));
                    stdData.add(8, rs.getString("father_office_address"));
                    stdData.add(9, rs.getString("cont1"));
                    stdData.add(10, rs.getString("occupation_mother"));
                    stdData.add(11, rs.getString("mother_office_address"));
                    stdData.add(12, rs.getString("mname"));
                    stdData.add(13, rs.getString("cont2"));
                    stdData.add(14, rs.getString("caddress"));
                    stdData.add(15, rs.getString("paddress"));
                    stdData.add(16, rs.getString("sex"));
                    stdData.add(17, rs.getString("addate"));
                    stdData.add(18, rs.getString("division"));
                    stdData.add(19, rs.getString("division"));


                }
                System.out.println(stdData.get(16) + "SFsdf");
                //System.out.println(stdData.size());

                con.close();

            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public List<String> returnStd() {
            //System.out.println(stdData.size() + "fraaksfrafi");
            return stdData;

        }

        public void printstd()  {
            //ArrayList<String> inter1 = (java.util.ArrayList) returnStd();
            //for (int i = 0; i < stdData.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(stdData + "faisal rafi");
                System.out.println(stdData.size() + "muhammad faisal muhammad rafi");   
            //}

            System.out.println("fsdf");
        }
/*      public static void main (String[] args) {
            ReadingStd reader = new ReadingStd();
            reader.readStd("czc");
            reader.printstd();
        }*/
    }
```

jsp page

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" 
    language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
    <%@ page import="school.ReadingStd" %>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <% ReadingStd dbData = new ReadingStd();
    ArrayList<String> stdData1 = new ArrayList<String>((java.util.ArrayList) dbData.returnStd());
    String [] stdData = new String[20];
    for (String stdData2: stdData1) {
        System.arraycopy( stdData2, 0, stdData, 0, 20 );
    }



    %>

    <label>Student ID</label>
    <input name="stdid" type = "text" value="<%= stdData[0]%>"></br>

    <label>Student Name</label>
    <input name= "stdName" type = "text" value="<%= stdData[1]%>"></br>
    Date Of Birth <input type="date" value = "<%= stdData[3]%>"></br>
    <select name="gender">
    <option value = "<%= stdData[16]%>"></option>
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>

    </select></br>
    <label>class</label>
    <select name = "stdClass">
    <option value = "<%= stdData[4]%>"></option>
    </select></br>

    <label>Division</label>
    <select name = "division">
    <option value = "<%= stdData[18]%>"></option>
    </select></br>
    <label>Contact Address</label>
    <input name= "contactAdd" type = "text" value = "<%= stdData[14]%>"></br>

    <label>Permenant Address</label>
    <input name= "permAdd" type = "text" value = "<%= stdData[15]%>"></br>

    <label>Father Information</label></br>
    <label>Father Name</label>
    <input name="fName" type ="text" value = "<%= stdData[2]%>"></br>

    <label>Father Occupation</label>
    <input name="fOccup" type ="text" value = "<%= stdData[5]%>"></br>
    <label>Father Education</label>
    <input name="fEdu" type ="text" value = "<%= stdData[6]%>"></br>
    <label>Father Email</label>
    <input name="fEmail" type ="text" value = "<%= stdData[7]%>"></br>
    <label>Father Office Address</label>
    <input name="fOfficeAddd" type ="text" value = "<%= stdData[8]%>"></br>
    <label>Father Contact No</label>
    <input name="fcontact" type ="text" value = "<%= stdData[9]%>"></br>


    <label>Mother Information</label></br>
    <label>Mother Name</label>
    <input name="mName" type ="text" value = "<%= stdData[12]%>"></br>
    <label>Mother Occupation</label>
    <input name="mOccup" type ="text" value = "<%= stdData[10]%>"></br>
    <label>Mother Education</label>
    <input name="mEdu" type ="text" value = "<%= stdData[10]%>"></br>
    <label>Mother Email</label>
    <input name="mEmail" type ="text" value = "<%= stdData[19]%>"></br>
    <label>Mother Office Address</label>
    <input name="mOfficeAddd" type ="text"></br>
    <label>Mother Contact No</label>
    <input name="mcontact" type ="text" value = "<%= stdData[13]%>"></br>

    Date Of Admission <input type="date"name ="addmissiomdate" value = "<%= stdData[17]%>"></br>
    >
    <input name="addStd" type="submit" value="Add Student">


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but **what exactly** you think you are doing? Why you do not create a value class, e.g. `Student`, with fields and getters/setters to hold the values like `name`, `fname`, etc.? And what result do you expect from `System.arraycopy( stdData2, 0, stdData, 0, 20 );` when `stdData2` is String and `stdData` is an **array** of Strings?!

Comment: i solve the issue

Comment: @user8297824 Then post an Answer of your own so that you can accept it and thereby mark the Question resolved.